# Resources error

Tags: c#, xamarin, resources

when I in Resources make new folded Raw, in code I want to use:

```
player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw...);
```

it shows me Resources does not contain a definition for Raw. Why? Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but you might have to change the Access Modifier settings in your RESX from internal to public.

Comment: You already added a file inside the folder? It won't create the `Resource.Raw` while the folder is empty.